# Как сменить цвет гамбургера и почему он пропадает при скроллинге?

Tags: html, css

Не могу понять почему у меня пропадает гамбургер в некоторых частях секций, а именно при перелистывании с первой секции banner к секции ко второй секции `features` и в самой секции `features`.

Сам гамбургер находится в блоке `hamburger_wrapper` и ему задано свойство `mix-blend-mode: difference;`

Как устранить это и сделать так, чтобы гамбургер не перекрывался?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

2. Так же не могу понять, как сменить цвет гамбургера. Я использовал hamburgers.css и задал белый цвет так

```css
.hamburger-inner, .hamburger-inner:after, .hamburger-inner:before {
  
  background-color: #fff !important;
}
```

и он был белым, до того, как я задал для `hamburger_wrapper` свойство `mix-blend-mode: difference;`

Сам сайт [ссылка](http://c96180og.beget.tech/)

код [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/1hg407ca/)

Comment: Не уверен подойдёт ли тебе это, но если заменить margin на padding, то всё начинает работать. Т.е. заменить .content {margin-top: 120px; ...} на .content {padding-top: 120px; ...}

Comment: сработало. Но внизу второго блока снова перекрывается

Answer (score 0):

а почему

```
mix-blend-mode:difference;
```

и зачем оно тебя нужно для гамбургера?

просто ставь это все в CSS и меняй цвет на черный

```
.hamburger-inner, .hamburger-inner:after, .hamburger-inner:before {      
      background-color: black !important;
}
```

Comment: такое требование